# Unable to update cookies with new set of tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1, httpcontext

I have built an authorization server based on IdentityServer4. It works. But when I try to refresh the tokens using the backchannel, the request fails at the point of calling the AuthenticateAsync() method on the HttpContext. Basically, calling AuthenticateAsync() or SignInAsync() on the HttpContext fails. Worse still, even when I wrap the call in a try...catch block, no exception is thrown.

I have tried injecting the IHttpContextAccessor both as either Scoped or Singleton but the same result. I hasten add that the Authorization server returns the updated tokens but it is at the point of updating the cookies with the new tokens in the client application that the process stalls. I suspect that the issue is with the context but I can not seem to point to the exact problem.

Below is the code snippet

```cs
var accessToken = string.Empty;
var currentContext = _context.HttpContext;

// this line works perfectly
var refreshToken = await 
currentContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);

// the auth service returns the tokens in the stringified data object 
var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AuthenticationToken>>(data);

if (tokens.Any())
{
    // this is the line that fails
    var currentAuthenticateResult = await 
        currentContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");

    currentAuthenticateResult.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

    // even this fails
    await currentContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", 
        currentAuthenticateResult.Principal, 
        currentAuthenticateResult.Properties);

 }
```

The client application is written in .NET Core 2.1

I need help.

Comment: Can you confirm/deny whether the request the above code executes in does actually set a new cookie in the response headers?

Comment: I can confirm that the request does not set a new cookie in the response headers.

Comment: I think the issue is with react hot reload module. The client application is based on the ASP.NET Core 2.0 React template for VisualStudio. Anyone had similar challenges before?